# Realtime update for updated activity

Tags: getstream-io

I'm playing around with getstream.io, it's an amazing tool but I have a question regarding realtime updates.

I am connected to realtime updates of a feed via Javascript (simply following examples from getstream.io).

```
feed.subscribe(callback)
```

Which works beautifully, adding and removing activities to the feed triggers the callback function.
However if I (via python) update an activity of a feed.

```
e = feed.add_activity(editable)
e['content'] = 'Ooops'
client.update_activity(e)
```

I see that the update was successful if I call feed.get() but I don't get a realtime notification in Javascript, shouldn't I? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activity update API does not trigger a real-time update notification.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I'm able to work around it by sending a different activity type ('edit') which is fine. Only downside is superfluous "edit" data in the feed after the fact.